# Can I have multiple JSON-LD scripts in the same page?

Tags: seo, html, schema.org, json-ld, script

The below `script` appears if I check the “Display the site links search box” in All in One SEO General Settings:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "WebSite",         "name": "mywebsite.com",        "potentialAction": {
          "@type": "SearchAction",
          "target": "http://mywebsite.com/?s={search_term}",
          "query-input": "required name=search_term"
        }, "url": "http://mywebsite.com/"
        }
</script>
```

The below `script` appears if I configure the social sites under Social Meta:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "name" : "My Website",
  "url" : "http://mywebsite.com",
  "sameAs" : ["https://www.facebook.com/mywebsite","https://plus.google.com/+mywebsite","https://twitter.com/mywebsite"] 
}
</script>
```

1. Can I have multiple `ld+json` scripts in the same page?
2. If yes, what is the significance of the two scripts?
3. Do I need to configure additional parameters for these scripts or this is enough to boost my site's SEO ranking?

Comment: About multiple `script` elements for JSON-LD, see on Stack Overflow: [Best JSON-LD practices: using multiple <script> elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30723531/1591669)

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, you can.
2. The first script indicates the URL of internal site search to be shown in Google SERP between your main entry and sitelinks. The second script indicates your social media accounts to be shown in the Knowledge Graph.
3. The scripts don't boost your rankings, they just give Google clues about what to include in the SERP if your site is strong enough to have a search box or your brand is important enough to get a Knowledge Graph box.

[image]